# Send email to address windows phone

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to code for a click event of a button where the textbox strings are sent to the email entered in a textbox. The best solution I have found so far is this but the using directive `using System.Net.Mail;` isn't recognised in eclipse, not sure if this is because I'm developing for Windows Phone? How would I modify this code to suit the windows Phone SDK as I'm thinking the host could be resolved by setting it to the devices network. Or does anyone have a better solution of achieving this?

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Write the following code in the click event of send button:

```
MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage("from@abc.com", "to@abc.com", "subject", textbox.Text);

SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
objSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
objSmtpClient.Host = "000.00.0.00";
objSmtpClient.Port = 25;
objSmtpClient.Send(objMailMessage);
```

A snapshot of what my interface looks like:

[image: UI]

Comment: This is about what library to use, not textboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [native email task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
emailComposeTask.Body = "Append all your control strings here";
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";

emailComposeTask.Show();
```

Comment: Cool that looks like a fairly straightforward implementation will try it now.

Comment: Ho would I append further details to the body of the email.I tried using for example,` = idTextbox.Text + roomNoTextBox.Text` but that didn't work,is there a way of formatting the `emailComposeTask.Body` so that it contains multiple textbox info? thanks

Comment: It should work,  emailComposeTask.Body = string.Format("Id: {0} - Room No: {1}", idTextbox.Text, roomNoTextBox.Text);   if not debug the code and see what is assigned to the Body property.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot send mail using that library - it isn't supported on the platform. What you should use is [`EmailComposeTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for sending mails.